# MGT Components and IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, microsoft-graph-toolkit

Discussions about supporting IE11 aside (we have clients still running IE and we need our solutions to support it wherever possible), I am failing to get any MGT components to work in IE. This is consistent across our custom solutions, basic web parts and also the samples provided. Before I raise an issue in the repository, I want to verify if IE11 is supported by MGT Components to start with.

To eliminate anything in our custom solutions, I have:

- created a basic spfx web part according to this documentation:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/toolkit/get-started/build-a-sharepoint-web-part.
  This is as basic an example as I can create.
- forked the repository
  at: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/, built
  and deployed the example.

In all cases, modern browsers have no issue, but IE11 yields this error:

[image: IE11 error message with MGT Components]

Previously, polyfills were recommended for support in IE11:

```js
// import web component polyfills for browsers that need them
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
import 'core-js/es/number';
import 'core-js/es/math';
import 'core-js/es/string';
import 'core-js/es/date';
import 'core-js/es/array';
import 'core-js/es/regexp';
import '@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle.js';
```

These have been removed from the documentation and also the samples. Is this because IE11 support is handled another way or has support been dropped altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, very specifically the lack of web component support for ie11 in Sharepoint webparts caused us to need to stop supporting the browser. Along with Microsoft's [announcement](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/microsoft-365-apps-say-farewell-to-internet-explorer-11-and/ba-p/1591666) to drop support as well, we felt it was necessary to move on for future features.

Comment: This is what we thought - and makes perfect sense given the MS roadmap for supporting IE. I appreciate the clarification.